# Xamarin ios - How do i check for nil value

Tags: xamarin, null

I want to check for nil ( not null )objects before inserting object in to nsdictionary. How do i check that?

```
public override void DidReceiveData (MCSession session, NSData data, MCPeerID peerID)
        {
            if (data != null && peerID != null) {
                NSObject[] ObjectsArray = new NSObject[]{ data, peerID };
                NSObject[] KeysArray = new NSObject[]{ new NSString ("data"), new NSString ("peer") };
                NSDictionary dict = NSDictionary.FromObjectsAndKeys (ObjectsArray, KeysArray);
                NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.PostNotificationName (MultiPeerMasterController.MCDidReceiveDataNotification, null, dict);
            }
        }
```

Comment: not sure what your question is. if ( objectinst == null ) ??

Comment: whats the equivalent of objective nil ( not null ) in xamarin. data1 and data2 could be nil objective c references, so i want to check that condition because nsarray and nsdictioanry soesnt allow nil values

Comment: Can you show us an image of what you meant != null should be working so if that doesn't work for you then something else is wrong.

Comment: edited my code block checking for null

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` and `object` instead of NSObject and NSDictionary.

Example:

```
object[] ObjectsArray = new[] { data1, data2 };

string[] KeysArray = new[] {"data1", "data2"};

var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();

for (int index = 0; index < myInts.Length; index++)
{
    var object = ObjectsArray[index];

    // check for null here before adding it to the dictionary
    if (object != null)
    {
       dictionary.Add(KeysArray[index], ObjectsArray[index]);
    }
}

//convert to NSDictionary
var nsDictionary = NSDictionary.FromObjectsAndKeys (dict.Keys.ToArray (), dict.Values.ToArray ());
```

You will need to add `using System.Linq;` to get the `ToArray()` method

-- EDIT --

If you want to check for nil values inside an Objective-C collection, you need to use `NSNull`: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNull_Class/

In Xamarin you can do this by checking the value against `NSNull.Null`
http://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/MonoTouch.Foundation.NSNull/

Comment: if data1 or data 2 is nil, it is not covered under the != null condition. I have to use nsdictionary as its a requirement for one of the framework methods

Comment: `if data1 or data 2 is nil, it is not covered under the != null condition.` - Are you saying that `nil` in Objective-C is not the same as `null` in C#? I am not sure if that is true, however, if the goal to make sure all the objects inserted in the dictionary have a value, this would accomplish that.

I added a line at the end to convert to an NSDictionary.

Comment: i tested with != null condition and it escapes that and hence the question. so the check is very important to proceed forward with inserting keys and values

Comment: Ah, okay I think I see what you are getting at. Looks like to check to nil values in a Objective-C collection, you need to use `NSNull`. In Objective-C `The NSNull class defines a singleton object used to represent null values in collection objects (which don’t allow nil values)` -- that is straight from apple docs.  This also exists as singleton in Xamarin: http://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/MonoTouch.Foundation.NSNull/.  I updated my answer as well with this